# Script not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with this tiny script I wrote for a website I'm creating. I'm totally new to JavaScript, so forgive me if I'm missing something that might be obvious to you.

The aim of the script is to hide a div as soon as the page is loaded, and then to show it when the user clicks on an element in a dropdown menu. Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cdcpanel").hide();

$("#contrpanel").hide();

$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $("#cdcpanel").show(200, function() {
    });
    $("#contrpanel").hide(200);
});

$("#clickme2").click(function() {
    $("#contrpanel").show(200, function() {
    });
    $("#cdcpanel").hide(200);
});

$("#hideall").click(function() {
    $("#cdcpanel").hide(200);
    $("#contrpanel").hide(200);
});

});
```

As you can see, the divs `cdcpanel` and `contrpanel` are initially hidden. Clicking on the element called `clickme` will cause `cdcpanel` to be shown and `contrpanel` to be hidden. Clicking on the element `clickme2`, instead, will trigger the opposite event. The problem is that it won't work on other browsers apart from Firefox. I've tried it up on Chrome and IE and the result is that the div is initially hidden, but then nothing happens by clicking on the dropdown menu.
This script relies on JQuery. It's called at the beggining of the page using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsshow.js"></script>
```

Any suggestion on how to make things work is welcome! Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: Code looks fine. You should look at the console for errors.

Comment: ^ Good idea. Also, if the `#cdcpanel` and `#contrpanel` are to be hidden on page load, it'll probably be better to style them initially as hidden, so you avoid the possible nastiness of the element being displayed and then hidden, causing the page to reflow.

Comment: Code looks fine, try removing the jsshow.js and see if it works then, if it works, the problem is in that file.  

Also as Matthew said, it's better to not display them instead of 'hide' them; `$("#cdcpanel").hide();`to `$("#cdcpanel").css('display', 'none');` or even better, change it in your CSS file.

Comment: @matt where are *clickme* and *clickme2*? You mentioned dropdown menu, `click` event is not good idea for such elements, use `change` event instead.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that dropdown menu's option elements have click events. try change event.